# JFrame doesn't displayed the JMenuBar in Intellij

Tags: java, swing, intellij-idea, jframe, jmenubar

When I run the program, I see a blank window.
How am I able to solve this? Thanks you. What I did wrong?
Here is my code:

```
public class Environment{
    private JFrame frame;
    private JMenu jmenu;
    private JMenuItem menuItem;
    private JMenuBar menuBar;

    Environment(){

    frame = new JFrame("Notepad");

        menuBar = new JMenuBar();
        //menuBar.setVisible(true);
        jmenu = new JMenu("Test");
        menuItem = new JMenuItem("Open");

        jmenu.add(menuItem);


        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        frame.setSize(660, 350);

            // Set a main menu
            frame.setJMenuBar(menuBar);
            menuBar.add(jmenu);

    frame.setVisible(true);
}
}
```

Comment: The menu is displayed correctly and your frame is empty because you didn't add any component inside it.

Comment: @NarutoBijuMode Hello. Like a buttons, label etc?

Comment: Yes the frame is empty you should add some components  like JButton, JLabel... inside it. See [How to Use Various Swing Components](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/componentlist.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding label1 and button1 - You can fix layout etc. Suggest you to use Jpanel as well.

public class Enviornment {

```
    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        JFrame frame;
        JMenu jmenu;
        JMenuItem menuItem;
        JMenuBar menuBar;


        frame = new JFrame("Notepad");

            menuBar = new JMenuBar();
            menuBar.setVisible(true);
            jmenu = new JMenu("Test");
            menuItem = new JMenuItem("Open");

            jmenu.add(menuItem);

            JLabel label1 = new JLabel("My Name");
            JButton button1 = new JButton("Button");

            frame.add(label1);
            frame.add(button1);

            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            frame.getContentPane().setLayout(new FlowLayout());
            frame.setSize(660, 350);

                // Set a main menu
                frame.setJMenuBar(menuBar);
                menuBar.add(jmenu);

        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you. It works. It is a strange. In official documentation I didn't find information about what graphical elements required.